# Create a saved search using items that doesn't have any direct relationship in Netsuite

Tags: sql, netsuite

Is it possible to create a saved search that will show revenue, COG , deferred payment etc from sales order between items that doesnt have any direct relationship, they are from different tables. I have created an extensive search with quite a bit of formula for one table, now is it possible to join the tables in that saved search? Do I have to create searches for other tables (based on the previous one)? If so how do I combine multiple saved searches? is it through pivot tool? appreciate any pointer.

Thanks

Sam

Answer (score 1):

Normally you can't cross-search on tables which have no 2nd degree connection. I usually do by pulling the whole tables via search, transforming the results into objects and matching data via JS.

Here are some tools I have:
https://github.com/pipechang/netsuite.toolbox/blob/master/toolbox.api.js

*note I change these from time to time so don't link directly.

Comment: I also figured that Netsuite doesn't allow cross search, that is why I was thinking of trying out the pivot report tool.Thanks for the tip